# Matching URI with regex find replace

Tags: regex

I'm still learning Regex operations and I couldn't figure out how I can execute a regex that replace in a URI the "/" with "-" in an Apache rewrite rule expression. Assuming that It would be possible for as many "/" as existing in the incoming URI.

I tried `^\/?(([a-z0-9_\.-]+)\/)+$` and tested with `$1-$2` for `example1/example2` but i didn't work.

Can anyone help me with this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following lines in `mod_rewrite` in `.htaccess` in the root folder, or in the `vhost` configuration file in your Apache :

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule (.*)([^\/]+)\/([^\/]+)\/?$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}$1$2-$3
```

will rewrite

```
http://%{HTTP_HOST}/example1/example2
```

as

```
http://%{HTTP_HOST}/example1-example2
```

and

```
http://%{HTTP_HOST}/example1/example2/example3/example4
```

as

```
http://%{HTTP_HOST}/example1-example2-example3-example4
```

Comment: Is there a way to make it more generalized ? so it could be applied to 3 or 4 or 100 terms ? if i have `you/can/exchange/this/uri` to `you-can-exchange-this-uri` ?

Comment: The reason it wasn't validating in `regex101`, was because I hadn't escaped the forward slashes (which, as far as I know, you don't actually need to in `mod_rewrite`). I've edited the post above so that the regex will apply to 3 or 4 or 100 terms. (You won't see this in `regex101`, because it doesn't run the same rule repeatedly, unlike `mod_rewrite`).

Comment: Ok i'll test it in my apache . Thanks a lot @Rounin

Comment: The regex `\/?([^\/]+)\/([^\/]+)\/?$ /$1-$2` actually changes `Mysite.com/example1/example2/example3/example4` to `mysite.com/example3-example4`. That's a good start but i still need to do the operation repeatedly. (I flagged it with `[N]` without success)

Comment: My apologies, @IsmaH - I am trying to do the regex in my head rather than actually trying it out with a live server. I have updated the post above. It should all work now.

Comment: Don't worry ! You helped me a lot and a learnt a lot on Regex by searching. Thank you very much. Your solution is working like charm !

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use

```
\/    '-'
```

preferably with the 'g' flag to replace every slash in the Uri. That way (in javascript)

```
"example1/example2".replace(/\//, '-');
```

returns

```
"example1-example2"
```

Comment: I have to do it in apache. Since I've got a Cache server between apache and the website, this have to be done this way. Otherwise your solution would have been good to take.